# Create user for connecting via FTP in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ftp

I want to create a FTP user for a certain path on my webserver. I use Ubuntu + nginx;

I found only this code on the internet but I want to set a password for this user and have him access just one folder+subfolders of that and have read+write permissions :

```
adduser -c john
```

Comment: Which FTP server are you using, or going to use?

Comment: I will use the FTP server of my website

Comment: `echo -e 'password\npassword\n' | sudo passwd john`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the user to one specific folder and subfolders, you might need a more advanced setup.

SFTP is a *decent* option for this, though not perfect. See this blog [article describing the process](http://blog.famzah.net/2011/02/03/secure-chroot-remote-file-access-via-sftp-and-ssh/).

Note that the current answers don't address the issue of limiting the user to a specific directory.  Nor do they address that FTP users are often different from system users.  The command `adduser -c john` is creating a system user on Ubuntu rather than a user within a specific FTP software system.

Hope this helps.